# View help. Pulling data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Okay, I need some major help with this subject.  This is what I need the view to do.  It needs to take Sum of the DKP_Change Column in the Attendance table

```
 SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) FROM Attendance AS a GROUP BY Name
```

add the value of the initial DKP from the characters table

```
 SELECT b.Inital_DKP FROM Characters AS b GROUP BY Name
```

Subtract the sum of the raid drops tabe cost

```
 SELECT SUM(c.Cost) FROM Raid_Drops AS c GROUP BY Name
```

I'm entirely new to the idea of VIEWS and i'm not sure where to begin with, the name of the view should be DKP, the columns should be Name and Total_DKP, where total dkp is calculated from teh above select statements.

Here are the creates for all 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `Attendance` (
 `Date` date NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `Hours` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Penalty` float NOT NULL,
 `Rank` set('Raider','Core','Elite') NOT NULL,
 `Rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `DKP_Change` float NOT NULL,
 `RecordNumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`RecordNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Characters` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Class` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Spec` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Position` set('Healer','Tank','DPS') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Healer, Tank, or DPS',
 `Usable` set('Cloth','Mail','Plate') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of Usable Armor? Cloth,        Mail, Or Plate',
 `Primary Stat` set('Agility','Strength','Intellect','Healer','Tank') NOT NULL COMMENT     'Used for Sorting Only(ie dps trinket with agility strength dps not eligible)',
 `Initial_DKP` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'DKP given at the start of current tier.',
 `Total_DKP` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Huge Complicated Mess.',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Raid_Drops` (
 `Record Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Date` date NOT NULL,
 `Name of Item` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Item Slot` enum('Main Hand','Off Hand','Head','Neck','Shoulder','Back','Chest','Wrist','Hands','Waist','Legs','Feet','Ring 1','Ring 2','Trinket 1','Trinket 2') NOT NULL,
 `Player_Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Cost` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Record Number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: is `name` present in all table? is there any `ID` which is the primary key? can you show the table definition?

Comment: add table definition of the table to the question so that people can play with it or keep your schema with required tables in sqlfiddle.

Comment: Yes 'Name' is present in every table.

Comment: I've added the `CREATE` commands for each table to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- Join the three tables in a subselect, grouping on `Name`
- Perform your calculations on the results of each subselect

The only part that's not entirely clear to me is if the names in `Characters` are unique or not. If they are, you can drop the group by. If they are not, the AVG might give you unexpected results.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT sumA
       , initialB
       , sumC
       , sumA + initialB - sumC
       , a.Name
FROM   (
         SELECT Name, SUM(DKP_Change) AS sumA 
         FROM Attendance 
         GROUP BY Name
       ) AS a
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT Name, Inital_DKP AS initialB 
         FROM Characters 
       ) AS b ON a.Name = b.Name
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT Name, SUM(Cost) AS sumC 
         FROM Raid_Drops 
         GROUP BY Name
       ) AS c ON c.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: The `Name` field in the `Characters` table is `UNIQUE` you are correct.

Comment: When I try to run your code I get "#1054 - Unknown column 'a.DKP_Change' in 'field list'"

Comment: @user1886669 - I have removed the table aliasses in the subselects. Could you try again?